# Tell Maven to look in repos for parent pom before looking in file system

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Per Maven documentation Maven will only look in local and remote repos for a parent pom after it fails to find it locally.  The best solution I've found to dummy this out is by adding

```
        <relativePath>.</relativePath>
```

which is obviously a kludge and produces warnings (as it well should).  Maven seems to be like file-system coupling when dealing with parent modules and multi-module projects so this is the only way I see to have both of those co-exist without something that feels obviously wrong (e.g. inheriting from a filesystem child).

Comment: @jalynn2 How do you tell Maven to look in repos for parent pom before looking in file system?

Comment: What's the need of that? Why would you like to drive maven to look into the remote remotes before looking into the file system? Sounds like a basic problem with multi-module builds etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise see my comment on the below answer.  I was imagining a problem where there wasn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference the parent pom using the  tag:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parentpom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

You must install the parent pom into your local repo using the `mvn install -N` command from the directory that contains the parent POM.

Comment: oh, yeah I was being very silly.  I conflated looking in the parent directory first, with simply ignoring the coordinates you supply entirely in lieu of whatever is lying in the parent directory.